# How to optimize matlab code for gpu

Tags: matlab, gpu

I have a function like,

```
function ObjVal=fun(Chrom,a)

  [Nind,Nvar] = size(Chrom);
  [m n]=size(a);

  for i=1:Nind
    c=Chrom(i,:);
    Cmat=repmat(c',1,n);
    ax=abs(sum(Cmat.*a)).^2;
    ObjVal(i)= 10*log10(max(ax)./(mean(ax)));
  end;
```

Chrom=16*16 and a=16*1024 array. I'm trying to find the fastest way on gpu. Only gpuarray is slower. When I use arrayfun or bsxfun I get some errors.

```
function valmult=mult(Cmat,a)

  valmult=abs(sum(Cmat.*a)).^2;
```

ax=arrayfun(@mult,Cmat,a); I get 
***Function passed as first input argument contains unsupported or unknown function 'sum'.***)

I am new in MATLAB with GPU. Any suggestions which way is the best and how can I maximize code performance with gpuarray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things will be better if you can eliminate the for-loop. It can be done by the following code.

```
ax_mat = (Chrom * a).^2;
ObjVal = 10 * log10(max(ax_mat, [], 2) ./ mean(ax_mat, 2));
```

On the other hand, the heaviest operation in the code, the matrix multiplication of `Chrom * a`, is too small (16x16x1024) to fully utilize the GPU. You may find that even with the improved code, GPU is still slower.